# How to specify bookmark levels with pdfpages?

Tags: pdfpages, bookmarks

I'm using the `\includepdf` command from the `pdfpages` package like this:

```
\chapter{Code}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,subsection,2, Conditions, mylabelA}]{fname1}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,subsection,2, Blocks, mylabelB}]{fname2}
```

The chapter toc is fine but the bookmarks for the included pdfs are at the section level, aligned with the section title (Introduction):

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{toc.0}{Contents}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.1}{Code}{}% 2
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section*.1}{Introduction}{chapter.1}% 3
\BOOKMARK [2][-]{section*.2}{Conditions}{chapter.1}% 4
\BOOKMARK [2][-]{section*.3}{Blocks}{chapter.1}% 5
```

How do I specify that the bookmarks should be at the subsection level so they nest underneath the section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an anchor:

```
      Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not
(hyperref)                be the same. Added a new anchor on input line 26.
```

Add it with \phantomsection:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Code}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,subsection,2, Conditions, mylabelA}]{example-image}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,subsection,2, Blocks, mylabelB}]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is the phantomsection needed? Shouldn't the refstep in chapter be enough to provide an anchor? (just wondering)

Comment: @daleif: the chapter has its anchor, the problem is the following \addcontentsline,

Comment: But shouldn't that anchor be "global" so others can access it, or am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: @daleif: The bookmarks try to build an hierarchical structure, the section bookmark is a level below the chapter. This doesn't work with one anchor. hyperref realize this.